# Running PHP scripts with Bolt CMS

Tags: php, html, web, content-management-system, bolt-cms

So, this might be a stupid question. Bear with me, I'm new to CMS usage :P

Anyways, I'm using Bolt CMS to create a very simple website. For it, I just need a simple contact form, which means my server needs to be able to send out an email. I want to use PHP for this.

Now, how exactly should I handle this with Bolt CMS? The default configuration does not allow .php files to be uploaded, however I could easily change this in the main configuration, to allow for its type. My first guess was to try and upload it to either the theme folder, or the file folder for the theme. However, when I try to upload .php files they don't even show up in the folders I upload them to, even though it says the file was uploaded successfully. However, I'm unsure this would even be the best way to handle PHP scripts with Bolt CMS.

Anyone got any inputs to this? :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, Bolt will not allow you to run PHP scripts from inside Bolt. If this is something you need to have, there are two options:

- Make it standalone. Create a contact.php on the server that handles it, and link to that.
- The better solution would be to use an extension for that. [Simpleforms](http://extensions.bolt.cm/view/28e36add-bb48-4692-be50-e677f73b8f89) (easy to implement, with a fair share of options), [BoltForms](http://extensions.bolt.cm/view/24e8f80a-4c9e-11e4-866c-43d66b93a270) (more options and allows for more control over the fields as well as uploads) or [Simple Contact Form](http://extensions.bolt.cm/view/272bed93-9524-11e4-866c-43d66b93a270) (very bare bones, but might be what you need).

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) I think I will go for one of the extensions, then! So, does this mean that if l you ever require functionality bolt does not support (like costum PHP scripts), you will need to implement it through extensions?